# Given two vectors norm, calculate the distance between their terminal point

Tags: vectors

Given two vectors, u and v with norm of 4 and 3 respectively and also that they are of opposite directions, what is the distance between their terminal point?

would the distance be the same as $||u-v||$?

Am unsure about my answer hence would like some confirmations.

- Assume $u=(4,0)$,$v=(-3,0)$, $||u-v||=7$

Comment: You are absolutely right. Note that if e is a unit vector in the direction of u then u = 3e and v = -4e so u-v =7e.

Answer (score 1):

Well a vector doesn't have a "terminal point" because a vector doesn't have a fixed location.

But if $u=(4,0)$ and $v=(−3,0)$, then certainly $\|u−v\|=7$.